# Is it possible to load in a same context from differents connection string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to load in a same context from differents connection string?

I have 4 identical databases. Identical in structure but each of them contains specific data. I have on context.

```
 Namespace.Data.dbContext dbContext_1 = new Namespace.Data.dbContext();
 Namespace.Data.dbContext dbContext_2 = new Namespace.Data.dbContext();
 Namespace.Data.dbContext dbContext_3 = new Namespace.Data.dbContext();
 Namespace.Data.dbContext dbContext_4 = new Namespace.Data.dbContext();
```

but in my config file I have this

```
<add name="dbContext_1" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
<add name="dbContext_2" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
<add name="dbContext_3" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
<add name="dbContext_4" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And I get an exception because Entity Framework tell me it doesn't find the connection string for dbContext.

It seems EF load by default a connection string with his class name. Correct? How can I make it load other connection string?

Comment: Wich version of EntityFramework are you using ? Do you use T4 templates to generate your DbContext code ?

Comment: EntityFramework 6 and I use T4 templates to generate my DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) has an overload that allow you to specify the connection string or the connection string name to use.

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    // You can pass either dbContext_1, dbContext_2, dbContext_3, dbContext_4 as connection string name
    public YourContext(string nameOrConnectionString) 
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

If your context does not have this overload, you'll have to update your T4 template to add it. Locate this part in your template :

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
{        
    // This will generate the default constructor    
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    {
<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
<#
}
#>
    }

    // Removed this part for readability
}
```

Then modify it to add the overload your need.

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
{        
    // This will generate the default constructor    
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : this("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    {
    }

    // This is the overload you need
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
<#
}
#>
    }

    // Removed this part for readability
}
```

With that you should be able to tell your context wich database to connect.

Comment: Thank you. do you know why they (the creator of default template) didn't added this by default? Is it possible to find better/updated template?

Comment: I don't know why sorry. I think it's the default behavior of the scaffolder from the EntityFramework package.